# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'hod_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'student1' 0.000 sec?

Tags: mysql

```
create table Hod(
 BranchId int(5),
 Branch varchar(10),
 Hod_Name varchar(10),
 Hod_number int(15),
 foreign key (BranchId) references student1(BranchId)
);
```

Comment: Have you looked up the fine manuals? You need an index on the field for which you want the foreign key to apply. In this case, BranchId in Student1.

Comment: You should post create table statement for `student1` table, not `Hod` table twice

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON student1 (BranchId);`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the referenced field before creating the foreign key:

```
alter table student1 add index(BranchId);

create table Hod(
 BranchId int(5),
 Branch varchar(10),
 Hod_Name varchar(10),
 Hod_number int(15),
 foreign key (BranchId) references student1(BranchId)
);
```